# Intercepting query in DbContext

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, azure-sql-database, dbcontext

I am working on a project using SQL Azure. In order to handle Sql Azure Transient Errors I am using Transient Fault handling framework.

I have a class MContext which inherits from DbContext
I wrote a method override for entity framework SaveChanges() method in this class as below:

```
private ITransientErrorDetectionStrategy errorDetectionStrategy = new SqlAzureTransientErrorDetectionStrategy();

private RetryPolicy policy= new RetryPolicy(errorDetectionStrategy, 3);

 public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            return policy.ExecuteAction(() =>
            {
                return base.SaveChanges();
            });
        }
```

This way I don't have to make code changes throughout my project where ever SaveChanges() is called.

I want to know if there is a way to do the same for LINQ queries.

For example:

```
policy.ExecuteAction(() =>
            {
                var x = from user in context.Users select user.Id;
            });
```

Instead of making code changes throughout the project by adding the

```
policy.ExecuteAction(() =>
            {
});
```

block for all the linq queries and enforcing others in the team to do the same, is there a way to intercept the linq query within the MContext class and apply the Transient handling?

I can write an extension method and call it on all the queries, but again that would require code change throughout the project.

I want to handle it in one place just like overriding the SaveChanges() method and not make changes all over the project.

Thanks for your help!
Mahesh

Comment: Keep in mind that the queries should execute until they're enumerated, so your example might not be that useful. Also, take a look at Entity Framework 6's [Interception](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Interception) and [Connection Resiliency](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Connection%20Resiliency%20Spec) features.